# How to import Yahoo Mail contacts into Google?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, yahoo-mail

I need help with importing my Yahoo Mail email addresses to my Gmail contacts list, using a Samsung Galaxy S4. Whenever I try to email anyone from my Gmail contacts list, I can't because they aren't imported from my Yahoo Mail account.

Comment: Use the second method suggested by Chank. Exporting Yahoo contacts as .csv file is very easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the [Yahoo mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail) app from the Play Store, it will synchronize your contacts to your phone's address book, and pull them up in any app, including Gmail.  The advantage of this method is that you will have an ongoing sync, meaning any contacts you add via Yahoo website will automatically appear on your phone, and vice-verse.

If you don't want to install the Yahoo mail app, you will need to use a computer.  First, export contacts on Yahoo website as a CSV file as described in [this walk-through](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/VI78.html?impressions=true):

1. Go to Yahoo mail website on your computer.
2. Click on the "Contacts" button, and then go to Actions -> Export...
3. Select the "Yahoo CSV" option, click the "Export Now" button, select somewhere on your computer where to save this file, and click "OK".

Then you import the CSV file into your Google account as described [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14024?hl=en):

1. Sign into Gmail.
2. Click Gmail at the top-left corner of your Gmail page, then choose Contacts.
3. Click the More button above the contacts list and select "Import..."
4. Click the Choose File button.
5. Select the CSV file you generated from Yahoo, and click the Import button.

This method is a one-time import, and any modifications you make to your contacts via Yahoo website will not propagate to your phone.  Instead, your contacts will appear in your Google account.